# Add class to query_posts loop

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to be able to add a class to posts from a query (which would appear under the  element, however I have only figured out how to wrap the posts with  which doubles up the element. I can't see a parameter for query_posts() to do this. Is it possible to use post_class() somehow in this loop?

```
$args = unserialize( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ) );
$args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1;
$args['post_status'] = 'publish';
query_posts( $args);

    if( have_posts()) : 
    ?> <article class="newcomment"><?php

        while( have_posts() ): the_post();
            get_template_part( 'loop-templates/content', get_post_format() );

                endwhile;
    endif;
```

I just want to have each post from this loop have a class added called "newcomment" so that I can manipulate via javascript. Any help greatly appreciated, thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

The posts are being displayed based on the code in the loop-templates/content-[post-format] files. You should be able to add the class by editing the code in those files.

You can check the post type within the loop like so:

```
<?php $add_class = "";
if( get_post_type() == 'my_post_type' ) { $add_class="my-new-class"; }
?>

<div class="post-part <?php echo esc_attr( $add_class ); ?>">
//post stuff
</div>
```

Comment: I unfortunately can't do that because then this class is then added to all posts. I am loading more posts via ajax and need to manipulate these newly added posts via javascript.

Comment: See revised answer.